# How to use "Add Dockerfile" for a solution which uses ProjectReferences?

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio, monorepo

I have a mono repo with some common library projects and some WebApi projects.

```
Monorepo/
├── WebApiSolution/
│   ├── WebApiSolution.sln
│   └── WebApiProject/
│       ├── WebApiProject.csproj
│       └── Dockerfile
├── ...
└── LibsSolution/
    ├── LibsSolution.sln
    ├── LibAProject/
    │   ├── LibAProject.csproj
    │   └── ...
    └── LibBProject/
        ├── LibBProject.csproj
        └── ...
```

WebApiProject needs LibAProject. I did two things:

- I have added LibAProject to the solution WebApiSolution
- I have added a project reference to LibAProject to the WebApiProject.csproj

```
<!-- WebApiProject.csproj -->
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\LibsSolution\LibAProject\LibAProject.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\LibsSolution\LibBProject\LibBProject.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now I want to add a Dockerfile to WebApiProject with "Add | Docker Support...".
It does not work because of the project references that are not stored in the right path under the WebApiSolution.

Here is the failure message of Visual Studio:

```
An error occurred while adding Docker File support to this project.

In order to add Docker support, the solution file (.sln) must be located in the same folder or a higher folder than the target project file and all referenced project files (.csproj, .vbproj).
```

What is the best way to solve the problem with project references?

Comment: And where the solution file is located? Creating docker file is one time operation, so you can temporary create a .sln file in the root folder, reference all the needed projects, create the docker file (modify if needed) and then delete the .sln

Comment: @GuruStron I have added the sln files to the tree.

Comment: As I wrote, just try temporary creating a copy of `WebApiSolution.sln` in the root folder, generate docker file and delete the temp sln.

Comment: @GuruStron It works. The magic is that DockerfileContext is written to the csproj file. Unfortunately "COPY . ." copies now the whole Monorepository to the container. Tons of data. Manuelly I could fix that. But it would be nice to generate this Dockerfile somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 6+, and only need to publish to a container image you can use the new SDK .NET 7 SDK feature to publish to an image : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container